# Google Cloud Datastore timeout errors in python

Tags: python, google-cloud-datastore, google-app-engine-python, gcloud-python, google-cloud-python

I have a table in Google Cloud Datastore where I store a small data structure which is written in one Python service and read in another. I am using gcloud version 0.15.0. Here is the Python code that I use to write/read data to/from GCD:

```
from gcloud import datastore
import datetime
import json
class GCD(object):
def __init__(self, project_id):
    self.client = datastore.Client(project_id)

def put(self, table, key, data):
    with self.client.transaction():
        entity = datastore.Entity(self.client.key(table, key), exclude_from_indexes=['context'])
        entity.update({'context': json.dumps(data), 'created': datetime.datetime.utcnow(), 'done': True})
        try:
            self.client.put(entity)
        except Exception as e:
            print "GCD save failed with exception: %s" % e
    return None

def get(self, table, key):
    entity_key = self.client.key(table, key)
    entity = None
    try:
        entity = self.client.get(entity_key)
    except Exception as e:
        print "GCD read failed with exception: %s" % e
    if not entity:
        return None
    else:
        return json.loads(entity['context'])
```

I am observing a large number of read/write failures with the message "The read operation timed out"; >5% failures which is quite contrary to the documentation that mentions an expected failure rate of 1 in 30K.

My questions then are:

1. Is it possible to increase timeout in the datastore.client.get and datastore.client.put calls? I am not looking for answers based on retries; already tried and don't want to depend just on retries.
2. Is there anything I should do when creating the table or setting up the client that can mitigate these timeout errors?
3. I read somewhere (https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gcloud-python/issues/1214) that the Python gcloud uses httplib2.Http which is not threadsafe and has timeout issues. Is there a way to use the (more stable) Python requests package?

Thanks,

Comment: Approximately how frequent are the calls to put() and get()?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `requests` or `urllib3` without any problems, see https://google-auth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user-guide.html#making-authenticated-requests

AFAIK the requests default timeout is None, so it waits infinitely (until the server closes it.) You can can pass own `Session` to the `AuthorizedSession` also, which override the `request` method and sets the default timeout as you like.

If you still experience the problem, then I recommend some retry mechanism :-) Wath the issue https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-python/issues/2694